# Couldn't start the android-emulator for armv8-aarch64 and armv7 architectures

Tags: 20.04, android, qt, android-studio, android-emulator

I have the following error On running Android emulator with `armv8-aarch64` and `armv7` architectures.

```
cannot add library /home/asmmo/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
added library /home/asmmo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
cannot add library /home/asmmo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1: full
INTEL-MESA: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

qemu-system-aarch64: PCI bus not available for had
```

I edited these two files `/etc/sysctl.d/99-i915psp.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.d/60-madapi.conf` to put `dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0` put there is no use.

The result of `dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0` in the terminal is `1` even after the edit and restarting.

The emulator works well with `x86-64` architecture.

How to solve this problem?